# Return the key, where the value is a vector, when asking for a value that might be in that vector

Tags: clojure

Given the following data structure, I want to ask for "services-list" (a component) and receive back "entity-list" (a style).

```
(def style->components {"entity-list" ["services-list" "employee-list" "clients-list"]})
```

My solution is not so elegant:

```
(defn get-style-name [comp-name]
  (-> (filter (fn [map-entry]
                (let [v (val map-entry)
                      found-comp (some #(= % comp-name) v)]
                  found-comp
                  )) style->components)
      first
      first))
```

Is there a better way? Perhaps my problem started with the way I structured the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add another alternative, nested sequence operations usually lend themselves to replacement with `for`:

```
(defn get-style-name
  [comp-name]
  (first
    (for [[style-name comp-names] style->components
          comp-name'              comp-names
          :when (= comp-name comp-name')]
      style-name)))
```

Still, I'd prefer a solution where the mapping of component name to style name is pre-computed, e.g.

```
(def get-style-name
  (->> (for [[style-name comp-names] style->components
             comp-name               comp-names]
         [comp-name style-name])
       (into {})))
```

This way, you avoid traversing the `style->components` map on every lookup.

Answer (score 3):

you can make it shorter and more clojurish this way:

```
(defn get-style-name [comp-name]
  (ffirst (filter (fn [[_ v]]
                    (some #{comp-name} v))
                  component->style)))
```

1. there is a function `ffirst`, that works exactly like `(first (first %))`
2. using a destructuring in the filter function signature, you can retrieve the value of the map entry, avoiding unneeded `let`
3. instead of this function in `some`: `#(= % comp-name)` it is quite common to use the set: `#{comp-name}`

then you can use `some` instead of `filter`, as it returns the first logical true value returned by function, so you can remove `ffirst`:

```
(defn get-style-name [comp-name]
  (some (fn [[k v]]
          (when (some #{comp-name} v) k))
        component->style))
```

also, if you change your data structure to use set instead of vector, you can make it even shorter:

```
(def component->style {"entity-list" #{"services-list" 
                                       "employee-list" 
                                       "clients-list"}})

(defn get-style-name [comp-name]
  (some (fn [[k v]] (when (v comp-name) k))
        component->style))
```

Comment: Can we edit your answer so that `component->style` becomes `style->components`, which xsc believes is the more conventional name? If you believe it is actually best the way it is then I will edit the question and xcs's answer to be the way they were originally, which included xsc's reservation about the name.